# Katalon Unable to set x-www-form-urlencode params in http body

Tags: groovy, katalon-studio

In the Katalon Studio, I'm unable to use x-www-form-urlencoded in HTTP body. When I add parameters to x-www-form-urlencoded in HTTP Body and trying to save is not saving the params.

Please help me on how to handle this one.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://forum.katalon.com/t/http-body-cannot-add-new-parameter/40934) on Katalon forum:

> Saving while editing your parameter name/value will cause it to be removed. You should quit editing parameter name/value before saving.

Comment: I have done the same thing, still, the parameters removing.
I'm using Katalon 7.2.6

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to add HTTP Body x-www-form-urlencoded params

1. Add all the parameters in the "x-www-form-urlencoded" tab
2. Click on "text" which is left beside of x-www-form-urlencoded tab
3. Now save Ctrl+S
4. Go to "x-www-form-urlencoded" Tab
5. Now save Ctrl+S

Now, the parameters will not remove